# GLM BACI analysis in R

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to conduct a BACI analysis in R using logistic regression. Due to the use of reference levels in the output of GLMs, I am having difficulty interpreting my results. Has anyone had any luck retrieving a summary of all pairwise interactions?

(`Depth` is a continuous predictor variable, but I can convert it to a categorical if necessary.)

```
Towards   <- c(4,7,9,0,15,10,11,23,1,4)
Total     <- c(6,14,10,7,15,12,20,41,5,8)   
Depth     <- c(-.3,-.25,-.21,-.17,-.05,0,0,.25,.5,.56)
DPM       <- c("Pre","Post","Pre","Pre","Post","Pre","Post","Post","Post","Pre")  
Proximity <- c("Far","Near","East","East","East","Near","Far", "Far","Near","Far") 
Area      <- c("DPM","Control","Control","DPM","Control","Control",
               "DPM","DPM","Control‌​","DPM")
Data      <- data.frame(Towards,Total, Depth, DPM, Proximity, Area)}

mod       <- glm(cbind(Towards, Total-Towards) ~ DPM*Site*Depth, 
                 data=LogReg, family=binomial('logit'))
```

Comment: I think that a reproducible example *is* necessary here.

Comment: Original post edited to include some example data and my model. Thanks for any and all help!